# Удалённое подключение к linux

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, openssh

Так, у меня есть условный сервер с debian, как мне подключиться к нему из под windows что бы при этом "удалённый доступ" включался автоматически со старта системы. Если что-то непонятно в моих объяснениях - прошу в комментарии

UPD: Мне надо что бы именно linux запускал нужные ему процессы в виде Putty и позволял к себе подключится из вне

Comment: Непонятно, зачем нужно подключаться и как должно выглядеть автоматическое подключение со старта системы. Вы хотите видеть открытую консоль при включении компьютера или что?

Comment: Мне надо что бы сервер при запуске запускал удалённый доступ к себе

Comment: То есть вам нужно, чтобы linux-сервер запускал программы на чужом компьютере? Тогда нужно наоборот делать удалённое подключение к windows из линукса.

Comment: Господи, я знал на что шёл. Компы стоят в метре друг от друга в локальной сети. Мне нужен наиболее быстрый и легкий способ подключится из под Windows к Linux, при этом надо что бы linux запускал нужные ему программки по типу putty(у сервера не будет не клавы, не мышки, не монитора)

Comment: Фраза «linux запускал нужные ему программки по типу putty» непонятна прям вообще. Обычно под putty подразумевается ssh-клиент на windows — зачем запускать его в линуксе и зачем он ему нужен?

Comment: Лёгкий способ подключиться из Windows к Linux — это ярлык putty на рабочем столе, куда уж проще-то?

Comment: Та я дебиль прост, мне надо что бы linux по кд запускал ssh сервер к которому можно подключится

Comment: В любом нормальном дистрибутиве linux (в том числе debian) ssh-сервер запускается автоматически без каких-либо дополнительных действий. Если в вашем это случае это не так, значит расскажите, как вы добились того, что ssh-сервер у вас перестал запускаться сам

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100222/discussion-between-terrorka-and-andreymal).

Comment: Дело в том, что этот вопрос настолько, гм, неожидан, что начинаешь думать в стиле "Ему ssh нужен? Да нет, иначе бы не спрашивал. Да нет, вроде же ssh... Или нет?". ssh настолько стандартен в линпсомире что даже не задумываешься...\

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Linux по кд запускает SSH, просто подключайся к компу напрямую в локале или открывая 22 порт на роутере и просто скармливай ему имя пользователя и его пароль

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы из Windows подключиться к Линукс через Putty, на Линуксе должно быть запущено sshd.
А в Windows сделайте батник с параметрами запуска Putty, чтобы он автоматом цеплялся к Линукс, и поместите в автозагрузку. 
А вообще не очень ясна ваша цель. Попробуйте разбить вашу задачу на части